# Why my custom domain not showing S3 bucket data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I am trying to create a static website using Amazon S3 and Route 53 services. I created a bucket with my domain name only but after creating "A" record set in Route 53 hosted zone I am unable to access my data via domain name. And I updated name servers as well in hostinger (from where I purchased the domain).

I followed [Example: Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) even though I am facing the issue.

I enabled static website hosting as well and added a bucket policy which allow public to read my data.

Can you explain the resolution briefly?

Comment: What happens when you try access your domain? Please describe the issue

Comment: Can you access the bucket via the S3 web-hosting URL? Did you use `Alias=Yes` when defining the record in Route 53? Can you resolve the domain name to an IP address (eg with DNSLOOKUP)?

Comment: hey @WarrenG , 
The issue got resolved automatically. it took some time yo update name servers that's it.